# Add async method result to dtatable column

Tags: c#, async-await

My code:

```
public async Task<DataRow> GetForm(int id)
{
    DataRow row = await ExecuteOneRowQueryAsync(id);
    DataTable dt = await SelectAsync();

    row.Table.Columns.Add("Col", typeof (DataTable));
    row["Col"] = dt; //throws

    return row;
}
```

It throws an error where I want to assign the datatable value to the cell `Coll`. It says

> The type of *dt* is *System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Data.DataTable]* but *DataTable* type is expected.

I guess something is wrong with the async code part. Is there any way to get it running ?

**EDIT**

The method is called from a web api controller

```
    public class Controller: ApiController
    {
        public Task<DataRow> Get(int id)
        {
            return _service.GetForm(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assume you need to have `await SelectAsync().Result;` but without seeing the missing code it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Equalsk - I thought that, but then the assignment would fail since `dt` is given an explicit type of `DataTable` rather than being declared `var`. So either something odd is happening here, the error isn't where the OP is indicating, or this *isn't the actual code*.

Comment: `await SelectAsync().Result` won't compile

Comment: As myself and Damien said you're not showing enough code or even necessarily the real code so nobody can do much more than guess.

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have `Task<DataTable>` or `var` in that place in actual code, the following code would work :

```
DataTable dt = await SelectAsync();

row.Table.Columns.Add("Col", typeof (DataTable));
row["Col"] = dt; // no error will be thrown
```

and you select async signatures would be like:

```
public async Task<DataTable> SelectAsync()
{
   ......
   ......
}
```

The error you have posted would come if you have code written like:

```
Task<DataTable> dt = SelectAsync();

row.Table.Columns.Add("Col", typeof (DataTable));
row["Col"] = dt; // now that error will come
```

Comment: Hi, my code looks exactly the same as yours, but I've added code (controller) which calls GetForm method. Do I need to add the await keyword also to the controller ?